# How can I do something before uninstalling my android app?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, uninstallation

I found how to detect uninstall event and test following code.

In **Receiver.java**:

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d(TAG, "received broadcast : " + action);
}
```

In **manifest.xml**:

```
<receiver android:name="....base.BaseAppReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/> 
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

But it detected when only other app was uninstalled.
I want to do something before uninstalling "my" app not "other" app.
Please, Let me know how can my app detect uninstalling event for processing something before uninstalling my app if it can.

Comment: Can you rephrase your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, sorry. If you put your files in the proper directories, they will be deleted automatically, but no other work can be done when your app is uninstalled.

Comment: I want to delete saved data with uninstall.
where is the proper directory?

Comment: @nao0811ta: Everything on internal storage (`getFilesDir()`, `getCacheDir()`, your standard SQLite database and `SharedPreference` locations, `openFileOutput()`, etc.) will be deleted on an uninstall. Also, files stored in `getExternalFilesDir()` and `getExternalCacheDir()` will be deleted on an uninstall.

Comment: Thank you so so much... I'll try getExternalFilesDir().
I used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() so far..

Answer (score 1):

You can not listen your own uninstall event. Just think about that **You are trying to call any class that is going to be uninstalled, how could it be possible?**

If you want to implement, then you need to make one more application called **WatchDog** which will take care for your application when it gets uninstalled..

Hope it will help you..!!!